# run ajax call to get form submitting data first, then run the following JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have to build a Django web app.

In the frontend, I want to run the ajax call to get the form submitting data first, then run the following JavaScript to process according to the real-time data passed from the backend.

bms/url.py:

```
path('content_checklist_name_url/', views.content_checklist_name_url, name='content_checklist_name_url'),
```

view.py:

```
def content_checklist_name_url(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
       Course_Form = ContentChecklistForm(data=request.POST)
        if Course_Form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'bms/index.html')
```

HTML:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/demo/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

function myFunction() {

                        Swal.fire({
  title: '',
  text: "Do you want to confirm entries?",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  cancelButtonText: 'No'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
     $("#myform").submit();
     $.ajax({
    url: '/content_checklist_name_url/',
    type: 'get',
    //async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
            //sleep(500);
    if (data.includes('saved'))
    {

        Swal.fire(
        '',
        'Entries have been saved.',
        'success' )
    } else {

        Swal.fire(
        '',
        'Duplicate Entry. This Course Code already exists.',
        'error')
  }


    },
    failure: function(data) {
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
    });




    }



    else {
    window.stop();
    }
})
}
```

But the ajax could not run into at all, some 500 error flashed after form submitting:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).
when debug, it runs from the first line of ajax, directly to the last line of ajax.

How could I run ajax to get the data(form submitting result) from the backend first then run the if condition: `if (data.includes('saved'))` ?  So I could do different pop up from the results passed from the backend in real-time.